# Set theory - what are these questions asking?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

For my Discrete structures class in school, we have the following homework problem:

[image]

Preface: I naturally associate the word `and` with the intersection operator $\cap$, for example: $x \in A \text{ and } x \in B \iff x \in A\cap B$.

#### a.)

To me a.) can be translated to the following:

$$A\cap B  = \emptyset \iff B\cap A  = \emptyset$$

I'm inclined to make my proof say that this implies $A\cap B = B\cap A$ which we can prove by stating the commutative law of set theory. I can't tell if it wants me to go beyond that statement and actually prove the commutative law though?

#### b.)

I thought this problem was going to have me show the distributive law of set theory which in this case would be $(A\cup B)\cap C = (A\cap C)\cup(B\cap C)$ HOWEVER I translate b.) to the following:

$$(A\cup B)\cap C = \emptyset \iff A\cap  C = \emptyset \land  B\cap C = \emptyset$$ Now, because statement 1 `and` statement 2 must be true I think I may be able to simplify it down to $\iff (A\cap C)\cap(B\cap C) = \emptyset$ but logically that does not make sense to me. We're trying to prove that C has no elements in common with A and C has no elements in common with B which you could just as easily do by simplifying it to $(A\cap C)\cup(B\cap C) = \emptyset$. The statement I was able to simplify it to ($(A\cap C)\cap(B\cap C) = \emptyset$) looks like it is more proving that $A$ and $B$ and $C$ have no common elements, namely $A\cap B\cap C = \emptyset$. Did I interpret it correct, and the problem is just kinda weird?

If my original interpretation is correct: $(A\cap C)\cap(B\cap C) = \emptyset$ then I believe the sets $A = \{1, 2, 3\}, B = \{4, 5, 6\}, C = \{3, 4\}$ proves their statement wrong.

#### c.)

I translate the c.) to:

$$(A\cap B)\cap C = \emptyset \iff (A\cap C)\cap(B\cap C) = \emptyset$$

Can I just use the distributive law here?

Am I interpreting these even close to correctly?

Comment: Your line reasoning for a.) and c.) seems correct to me. However there is something wrong in your argument for b.).

Comment: $(A \cap C) \cap (B\cap C) = \emptyset$ is not equivalent to $(A\cap C) = \emptyset \wedge (B \cap C) = \emptyset$. To see this, consider $A := \{1,2\}$, $B := \{2, 3\}$ and $C := \{1,3\}$.

Comment: @M.G Ok I think that makes sense, because the first one is saying all three sets have no mutually common elements (true), but the second does not have anything to do with all 3 sets having mutual elements, it is instead looking at two individual intersections separately

Comment: @M.G what trips me up is that the symbol $\land$ is essentially "and" I think, therefore I think well I should be able to sub it out with an intersection operator (not true of course)

Comment: Always use the definitions, What is your def'n of "A and B are disjoint"?..... For (c) let $A=\{0\}, B=\{1\}, C=A\cup B=\{0,1\}.$ Then $A\cap B$ is empty so it's disjoint from $C.$  But $ A\cap C\ne \phi \ne B\cap C.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) seems okay, Except that you do not need to *prove* the commutative law, just use it as a justification.

---

For (b) note that: Intersection $A\cap C$ is empty and intersection $B\cap C$ is empty *if and only if* the **union** of both these intersections is empty.

$$(A\cap C=\emptyset)\wedge (B\cap C=\emptyset) \iff (A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C) = \emptyset$$

---

Because, basically, deMorgan's Laws:
$$\begin{align} (P=\emptyset) ~\wedge~ (Q=\emptyset)
~\iff~ & \forall x~(x\notin P) ~\wedge~ \forall x~(x\notin Q)
\\[0.5ex] ~\iff~& \forall x~(x\notin P ~\wedge~ x\notin Q)
\\[0.5ex] ~\iff~& \forall x~\neg(x\in P~\vee~ x\in Q)
\\[0.5ex] ~\iff~& \forall x~\neg(x\in P\cup Q)
\\[0.5ex] ~\iff~& \forall x~(x\notin P \cup Q)
\\[0.5ex] ~\iff~& (P \cup Q = \emptyset)
\end{align}$$

---

For (c) you want to *disprove* : $(A\cap B)\cap C=\emptyset \iff (A\cap C)=\emptyset\wedge(B\cap C)=\emptyset$

Because, $(A\cap B)\cap C=\emptyset \nLeftrightarrow (A\cap B)\cup C=\emptyset$

Comment: Exactly! Logically that makes sense, however whenever I see logical "and" I think "well I have to put an intersection operator there"...Obviously I am wrong

Comment: This makes sense because A and C's common elements have nothing to do with B and C's common elements, therefore we should form a union and evaluate not an intersection

Comment: deMorgan's interpretation has be a bit confused:
$\forall x~(x\notin P ~\wedge~ x\notin Q) \iff \forall x~\neg(x\in P~\vee~ x\in Q)$
I read the first part before $\iff$ as "x does not appear in P and x does not appear in Q". To me this means x cannot appear in $P\cup Q$, and you're using it to show that x cannot appear in $P\cup Q$. But if $\forall x~\neg(x\in P~\vee~ x\in Q) = \forall x(x \notin (P\cup Q))$, why doesn't the previous line $\forall x~(x\notin P ~\wedge~ x\notin Q) \iff \forall x(x \notin P\cap Q)$?

If the Vee translates to $\cup$ why doesn't the wedge translate to $\cap$?

Comment: I guess I'm just confused as to why you turned the $\vee$ into $\cup$ after negating the $\wedge$. To me this means the $\wedge$ (without negation) would've normally been turned into a $\cap$, however $\forall x(x \notin P \wedge x \notin Q)$ is clearly equivalent to $\forall x \notin (P\cup Q)$. It seems that $\vee \text{ and } \wedge$ both get turned into $\cup$ regardless

Comment: @DomFarolino  When negating inclusion we do nothing to the set.  $\neg(x\in Y) \equiv (x\notin Y)$  $$\begin{align} \forall x~\neg( x\in P~\vee~ x\in Q) ~\iff~& \forall x~\lnot(x\in( P\cup Q) ) && \text{by definition of Union} \\[1ex] ~\iff~& \forall x~(x\notin (P\cup Q) ) && \text{by definition of Exclusion}\end{align}$$

Answer (score -1):

For a) I am with you up to here:

> I'm inclined to make my proof say that this **implies** $A\cap B = B\cap A$ which we can **prove** by stating the commutative law of set theory.

Where you say *implies* you probably mean *is implied by* or *follows from*.  And as far as “proving” $A \cap B = B \cap A$ from the commutative law of set theory, that's really the only content to the law.  So there's nothing to prove there—you can just mention it parenthetically.

For c), I'm not aware of a distributive law for intersection over itself.  But you could invoke the *associative* (and commutative) law for intersection and the fact that $C\cap C= C$:
$$
    (A \cap B) \cap C = (A \cap B) \cap (C \cap C) = A \cap B \cap C \cap C = A \cap C \cap B \cap C = (A \cap C) \cap (B \cap C)
$$

For b) I agree with Graham.

As for your question, “Do I need to prove the commutative law?”, that depends on the context of the assignment.  Is the law stated in your textbook before this exercise, or has it been covered in class?  If so, you are probably free to use it.

Comment: Surprised about the downvote. Is there something wrong or misleading about the answer? Happy to correct or improve.